# Show tbody toggle mode (multiple tables)

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a doubt with a draw,

The point is that the design you want to display by default tbody thead but hidden in the corresponding table.

I would like to know how I can display its corresponding table tbody to click a link in the thead A.Link

Some sugencia? I put the code I have half finished, it would only bring to show something like a toggle.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="#" class="link">Bundled Documents List <i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></a></th>
                <th>01/01/2000</th>
                <th><a href="#"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="des">Lorem input sum</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="des">Executed Builder Contract</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="#" class="link">Bundled Documents List <i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></a>

                </th>
                <th>01/01/2000</th>
                <th><a href="#"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="des">Executed Sales Contract</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="des">Lorem input sum</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("div.list thead a.link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the link from being followed
    $("div.list tbody").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xqb76/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after, but here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqb76/2/

Comment: If it is correct, but he would like to keep active only tbody and close the others?